# Again tabular. What is the best way to color a cell or a table? What is the problem?

Tags: tables, tabularx, cellcolor

Hi again (I´m sorry by English mistakes).

I've learned a lot here. This week I learned several ways to create a table joining cells, and also how to put colors in it.
However for some reason, two different models of producing the same table do not present a satisfactory result in cell colors, disappearing words or lines.
Is there any way to get around this using these same templates? At what point is the error?
How to color the background´s cell first?

[image]

Thanks for everyone.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,brazil, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.5cm ]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathpazo, amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier, amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{main}

\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}

\colorlet{slightgray}{LightSteelBlue3!25}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290912/horizontal-line-hline-inconsistent-behaviour
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
        \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.1pt}
        {\centering{
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \Xhline{1.2pt}%\hline
                    \multirow{ 2.1}{*} { \parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.0cm} {\centering \textbf{Question}}} & \multirow{ 2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering $a)$}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} { \parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $b)$}}  & \multirow{2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $c)$}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $d)$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{4.55cm}  {\centering \textbf{Score}}} \\ \cline{6-7}
                     & &  &  &  &  {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.3cm}  {\centering \textbf{Individual}}} & {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.25cm} {\centering \textbf{Team}}} \\ \hline
                 1. & & & & & &  \\ \hline
                     2. & & & & & &  \\ \hline
                    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{TOTAL}} & & \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
    }}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
        \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.1pt}
        {\centering{
                \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{slightgray}}c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \Xhline{1.2pt}%\hline
                    \multirow{ 2.1}{*} { \parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.0cm} {\centering \textbf{Question}}} & \multirow{ 2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering $a)$}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} { \parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $b)$}}  & \multirow{2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $c)$}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $d)$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{4.55cm}  {\centering \textbf{Score}}} \\ \cline{6-7}
                    & &  &  &  &  {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.3cm}  {\centering \textbf{Individual}}} & {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.25cm} {\centering \textbf{Team}}} \\ \hline
                    1. & & & & & &  \\ \hline
                    2. & & & & & &  \\ \hline
                    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{TOTAL}} & & \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
    }}}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
    {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
        \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.1pt}
        {\centering{
                \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{slightgray}}c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \Xhline{1.2pt}%\hline
                    \rowcolor{slightgray}
                    \multirow{ 2.1}{*} { \parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.0cm} {\centering \textbf{Question}}} & \multirow{ 2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering $a)$}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} { \parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $b)$}}  & \multirow{2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $c)$}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $d)$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{4.55cm}  {\centering \textbf{Score}}} \\ \cline{6-7}
                    \rowcolor{slightgray} & &  &  &  &  {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.3cm}  {\centering \textbf{Individual}}} & {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.25cm} {\centering \textbf{Team}}} \\ \hline
                    1. & & & & & &  \\ \hline
                    2. & & & & & &  \\ \hline
                    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor{slightgray} \textbf{TOTAL}} & & \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
    }}}
\end{table}



\begin{table}[H]
    {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
        \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.1pt}
        {\centering{
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \Xhline{1.2pt}%\hline
                    \multirow{ 2.1}{*} {\cellcolor{slightgray}} & \multirow{ 2.1}{*} {{\cellcolor{slightgray}}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} {{\cellcolor{slightgray}}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} {{\cellcolor{slightgray}}} & \multirow{2.1}{*} {{\cellcolor{slightgray}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{4.55cm}  {\cellcolor{slightgray}\centering \textbf{Score}}} \\ \cline{6-7}
                    \multirow{ -1.9}{*} {\cellcolor{slightgray} \parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.0cm} {\centering \textbf{Question}}} &
                    \multirow{ -1.9}{*} {\cellcolor{slightgray}\parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering $a)$}} & \multirow{-1.9}{*} {{\cellcolor{slightgray}} \parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $b)$}} &\multirow{-1.9}{*} {{\cellcolor{slightgray}} \parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $c)$}} & \multirow{-1.9}{*} {{\cellcolor{slightgray}} \parbox[c][0.7cm]{1.95cm} {\centering  $d)$}} &  {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.3cm}  {\cellcolor{slightgray} \centering \textbf{Individual}}} & {\parbox[c][0.7cm]{2.25cm} {\cellcolor{slightgray} \centering \textbf{Team}}} \\ \hline
                    \cellcolor{slightgray} 1. & & & & & &  \\ \hline
                    \cellcolor{slightgray} 2. & & & & & &  \\ \hline
                    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor{slightgray}\textbf{TOTAL}} & & \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
    }}}
\end{table}

{\centering{
        {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
            \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.1pt}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\columncolor{slightgray}}c
                    |>{\hsize=1\hsize}C
                    |>{\hsize=1\hsize}C
                    |>{\hsize=1\hsize}C
                    |>{\hsize=1\hsize}C
                    |c|c|}
                \hline
                \rowcolor{slightgray}
                & & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Scores}\\ \hhline{*5{>{\arrayrulecolor{slightgray}}-}*{2}{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}}
                \rowcolor{slightgray}
                \multirow{-2.2}{*}{\textbf{Question}} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$a)$} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$b)$} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$c)$} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$d)$} & \textbf{Individual} & \textbf{Team} \\
                \hline
                1. & & & & & & \\
                \hline
                2. & & & & & & \\
                \hline
                %\rowcolor{slightgray}
                \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor{slightgray} \textbf{TOTAL}} & & \\
                \hline
            \end{tabularx}
    }}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492140/help-to-tabular-how-to-set-different-sizes-of-cell-in-tabular-enviroment/492296#492296

\end{document}
```

Comment: About table design see https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/.  Coloring of tasble columns, rows, cells is problem, how used pdf viewer render table image. (lines in table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibikity. Note that for commutative diagrams, you should preferably use `tikz-cd` in the place of `amscd`. Also, `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions, and you shouldn't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`, to avoid any conflicts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, brazil, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm ]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathpazo, amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier, amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{main}

\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}

\colorlet{slightgray}{LightSteelBlue3!25}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290912/horizontal-line-hline-inconsistent-behaviour

\begin{document}

{\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.1pt}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\columncolor{slightgray}}c|*{6}{C|}}
 \hline
 \rowcolor{slightgray}
 & & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Scores}\\%
\hhline{*5{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{slightgray}}-}>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|}
  \rowcolor{slightgray}
 \multirow{-2.2}{*}{\textbf{Question}} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$a)$} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$b)$} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$c)$} & \multirow{-2.2}{*}{$d)$} & \textbf{Individual} & \textbf{Team} \\
 \hline
 1. & & & & & & \\
 \hline
 2. & & & & & & \\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor{slightgray} \textbf{TOTAL}} & & \\
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}
 }

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. I didn´t know about your tips. 
best regards

Answer (score 1):

Such diagram/tabulars/coloured grids are unbelievable easy to build with [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm ]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathpazo, cals}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}

\colorlet{slightgray}{LightSteelBlue3!25}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/7\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/7\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/7\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/7\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/7\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 7

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{1pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\sgray{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
    \def\cals@bgcolor{slightgray}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

% R1H1
\thead{%
\brow
    \sgray\nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Scores}\sgray
\erow
%R2H2
\brow
    \sgray\nc{lrb}\sc{\bfseries\vfil Questions}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil\itshape a)}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil\itshape b)}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil\itshape c)}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil\itshape d)}
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries Individual}
    \alignC\cell{\bfseries Team}\sgray
\erow
\mdseries
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R3B1
\brow
    \sgray\cell{1.}\sgray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
% R4B2
\brow
    \sgray\cell{2.}\sgray
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
\erow
%R5B3
\brow
    \sgray\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{\bfseries TOTAL}\sgray
    \cell{}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]